# Borrar caché de memoria RAM (linux) desde php

Tags: php, consola, cache

He creado un archivo .sh en mi aplicación,titulado: "cache2.sh" resulta que lo ejecuto con shell_exec(), sin embargo, no me ejecuta la línea que deseo.

El archivo lo ejecuto así:

```
$stats = shell_exec('./cache2.sh');
echo $stats;
```

y contiene:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
exit
```

Según la consola o terminal de linux devuelve: vm.drop_caches = 3 y en la terminal funciona correctamente al ejecutar el archivo.

No obstante al ejecutarlo desde php sí ejecuta códigos como echo "Muestra mensaje". Pero cuando intento con el código para borrar el caché no pasa nada.

No se si alguien podría ayudarme. O especificar si no es posible realizar la acción deseada??

Comment: necesitas tener permisos de superusuario, ya que el usuario de php no tiene los permisos necesarios para realizar la acción.

Comment: En el caso de linux, tienes que tener el permiso de super usuario para ejecutar determinados comandos por lo que veo estas usando sudo, siempre que lo ejeuctas por primera vez en la consola, te pide la password  ahi puede estar el problema.  Aqui te dejo un en lace que te puede ser de ayuda [enlace](https://thelinuxalchemist.wordpress.com/2017/08/28/ejecutar-comando-sudo-sin-contrasena/)

Comment: Probe con lo sugerido pero no m ha funcionado. A lo mejor estoy cometiendo algún error. Pero gracias por la ayuda